# In android phonegap application screen UI does not renders it showing patch on keypad area when keypad hides back

Tags: android, jquery, html, angularjs, cordova

When i click on any of textbox it opens the system keypad but after entering text if i click on any link of page instead of **clicking on Go button** of keypad it **it hides the keypad but keypad area shows random area or previous screen area and after going on another page it shows new page completely but while transition from one page to another it shows unmodified area**

***This is original screen before the entering text in textbox*** 
**[image: text box in phonegap application]**

***this is screen when i clicked on textbox***
[image]

***This is the screen when i clicked back button insted clicking on done button of textbox***
[image]

**So i tried meta tags but it still cuts the page if i dont click on the Go button on the keypad**

Comment: which version of phonegap you are using?

Comment: I am using CORDOVA VERSION = "3.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

Anyway its been too late, sorry i couldn't help before.

i think its because of the height issue on the page. When soft keyboard comes up the device changes the device height to the area where the keyboard is not covered. try to re assign the Page height when the soft keyboard hides.!!

i think it will solve the issue.

Thanks & Regards.